# Converting '?' into NULL in PySpark databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I work in databricks. I have a dataframe d which contains few columns with '?' string value. I want to covert these '?' values to NULL because I want to use dropna(['...']) function later to delete observations with NULL values. I have no idea how to do this, nothing works. I tried:

numpy:

> TypeError: 'DataFrame' object does not support item assignment

```
import numpy as n
d[d=='?']=n.nan
```

pandas:

> TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

```
import pandas as p
p.DataFrame.replace('?', 'NA')
```

and pyspark method - also doesn't work:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace
d.withColumn('workclass', regexp_replace('workclass', '?', 'NA')) \
  .show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use backslash to escape the question mark in the regex pattern:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace
df2 = d.withColumn('workclass', regexp_replace('workclass', '\\?', 'NA'))
df2.show(truncate=False)
```

If you want null, you can use

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, lit
df2 = d.withColumn('workclass', when(col('workclass') == '?', lit(None)).otherwise(col('workclass')))
df2.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. And maybe you know what should I use to delete observations with NAs? dropna(['...']) doesn't work as I thought it works.

Comment: use the second piece of code to replace with null

Comment: then you can replace the nulls using dropna

Comment: So df2.dropna(['workclass']).show(truncate=False) should work? I get an error "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str". Sorry for probably stupid questions, this is my first time with databricks

Comment: Done, there are 2 columns that cointain ?/nulls

Comment: I don't get an error but when I display the table [display(d2)]  it still contains those rows with nulls.

Comment: you need to assign it to another dataframe, e.g. `d3 = d2.dropna(...)`

Comment: Yeah, I've just discovered this. Thank you very much, you are very heplful. And last little question, I see that this withColumn function doesn't work with columns which name contain ".", e.g. "column.name". So I just need to change the colmun name to use spark functions?

Comment: use backticks (`\``) to wrap the column names